# Dúvida com location path asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma aplicação na pasta raiz do servidor funcionando normalmente, no web.config eu tenho logo após a tag configuration:

```html
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> </location>
```

Após criar uma nova pasta, eu subir uma nova aplicação é tenho as mesmas configurações, mais a página fica em branco.
Alguém sabe o que poderia está errado! agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução mais simples foi criar um subdomínio é adicionar o conteúdo do site, funcionou perfeitamente.